# How to remove default Metrics data provided by Spring Actuator

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am trying to get Production metrics for my application. I am using Actuator on top of Spring Boot. Actuator exposes an endpoint for that "/metrics". I have Autowired CounterService class to get my own metrics data. I will be displaying the metrics data in one of our Application Management UI. The problem here is that I don't want all the default metrics data, as the Response JSON given back by the /metrics endpoint is kind off heavy for me to parse and most of the default metrics data are useless for me and give it to the UI. I have gone through the [Spring Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html), I didn't get any help.

Appreciate your help on this!

Comment: why can't to wrap metrics coming from actuator with your own Custom class and and send this Custom class object back to UI

Answer (score 0):

Oh So I found a way to deal with the scenario. Actually Spring [This GitHub Link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/4654) pretty much solves my problem. Actuator Supports Reqex support to query for the data you need. So my url looks like this now : [http://{{hostname}}/metrics/counter.*.count](http://%7B%7Bhostname%7D%7D/metrics/counter.*.count) instead of this [http://{{hostname}}/metrics/](http://%7B%7Bhostname%7D%7D/metrics/). Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried wrapping the response class from metrics, with a Custom class?